# Meaning of "bolting down"

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

> It’s a matter of preparation — **bolting down** your water heater before an earthquake or actually reading the in-flight safety card before takeoff — but also of mental conditioning.

In the above sentence, what is the meaning of 
 **bolting down**?

I guessed as reducing the temperature instantaneously, is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually literal. It means to use bolts to attach your water heater to the floor or wall.

See [this site](http://earthquakecountry.info/daretoprepare/stuff/waterheater.html) that talks about the problem and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

*Bolt* in that case means "to fasten things together with a bolt."
"Cool something down" is the phrasal verb used when something is made cool or cooler. It doesn't imply it is done instantaneously, though.